# What is the correct way in RESTful API paradigm to describe resource statistics?

Tags: rest

Lets assume that we have some sort of `users` collection. Each `user` (single resource) has some sort of stats - number of comments, number of calls, number of anything. And each `users` collection may also have some sort of stats - global stats.

These stats can be anything from number of comments to something more complicated.

Currently I am thinking of two main ways of "integrating" stats to my RESTful API:

1. For each single resource `user` add special computed field - `balance`, `mediumAgeOfMaleFriends` etc. When performing `GET` request to `user` resource I'll loop for each field in query parameter `fields` and calculate corresponding values. Example: `.../user/123?fields=balance,name,email,mediumAgeOfFemaleFriends`
2. Under each resource create subresource called `reports` (or something like that), create report resource templates (with predefined configurations) and perform same `GET` requests like so: `.../users/123/reports/1?from=...&to=...`

But these two ways don't look like true RESTful ways.

Comment: I would refrain from adding new additional fields but instead add links, with meaningful link relations to the resources a client can use if interested in order to retrieve the statistics. This is similar to traditional Web pages where you can click a link to load the additional content. Such a link could be issued for a link relation name `preload` to hint a client to load such information preemptively; alternatively you can also use `prefetch` (see [further available link relations](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml))

Comment: @RomanVottner, any examples?

Comment: There are some interesting examples [here](https://nordicapis.com/tools-to-make-hateoas-compliance-easier/) and [here](https://sookocheff.com/post/api/on-choosing-a-hypermedia-format/).

Comment: Cassio already gave some links; other than that you have pretty much the whole Web as inspiration ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a RESTful convention per-se for stats or reports. Both your options seem reasonable to me (leaning more towards **Option 2** though).

Another alternative is to have a root resource for 'reports', e.g. `/reports/user/123`. This might come in handy in the future if you decide to extend reports to another resource, other than 'user'.

You can also have a look at [HubSpots Analytics - Reports API](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/analytics/get-analytics-data-breakdowns) for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do you think should these report endpoints look like under the hood? Should these endpoints also use `fields`?

Comment: It depends on the types of stats, in some cases they're calculated on daily basis (and cached), so it doesn't hurt to return all fields - a lot of the MI reporting endpoints that I used previously worked this way. In your case, given that you're calculating your fields on the fly, expecting the user to provide the field(s) makes sense as it saves you from making unnecessary calculations.